# XSLT node-set() function support in InDesign

Tags: xslt, adobe-indesign

I have xslt 1.0 module with `ext:node-set` function (`xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"`) and would like to use it in InDesign's CC (2014)  via `Import XML...` feature.

When I choose File -> Import XML..., select XML, then Apply XSLT -> Browser... and choose xslt, click OK - I get an error `Function 'ext:node-set' not supported`.

I've tried to replace a namespace to `xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"` and function call `xalan:nodeset` - the similar error `Function 'xalan:nodeset' not supported`.

Questions:

1. Can I use node-set function in InDesign?
2. Which xslt processor is using in InDesign?

Comment: Re your 2nd question, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: Re your 1st question, you can use `<xsl:value-of select="function-available('exsl:node-set')" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>`.

Comment: When I run Michael's code I am getting "Ginger Alliance" which means Sablotron and it should support exsl functions. Try to search on Sablotron specific usage as it looks like it is different from the other processors

Comment: I don't remember details of the Sablotron XSLT processor but an old article https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html suggests that, contrary to most other XSLT 1.0 processors, it simply allowed you to use XPath on result tree fragments without any need for a `node-set` extension function. So perhaps give that a try and simply try to run the code omitting the call(s) to the extension function.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you. Yes, you are right, no need to use extension function. It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sablotron processor by Ginger Alliance is using in InDesign. Ginger Alliance site available via Wayback Machine https://web.archive.org/web/20090430034418/http://www.gingerall.org/index.html. Regarding https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html#tab.namespaces, Sablotron `Can operate on result tree fragments directly`, i.e. no need to use node-set or nodeset functions.

Example:

```
<xsl:variable name="items">
  <item>1</item>
  <item>2</item>
  <item>3</item>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="function-available('ext:node-set')"> <!-- for EXSLT compatible processor -->
    <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set($items)//item">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise> <!-- for InDesign -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$items//item">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```